# How to inject values without explicit calls?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm familiar with dependency injection concepts and its benefits, but using frameworks that would handle this business for me gets kind of confusing.

This question is valid for any DI framework, but I will stick to the Guice with this question.

**The problem**

Let's say, I have following classes:

```
public interface Tea {

    void prepare();

}

public class GreenTea implements Tea {

    public void prepare() {
        System.out.println("Preparing Green Tea");
    }

}

public class BlackTea implements Tea {

    public void prepare() {
        System.out.println("Preparing Black Tea");
    }

}
```

Without frameworks, in my main method, I would do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tea tea = new GreenTea();
        tea.prepare();
}
```

With the help of Google Guice Inject I could get futher and do something like this:

```
public class TeaModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
        bind(Tea.class).to(GreenTea.class);
    }

}

public class Main {

    @Inject
    private Tea tea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TeaModule());
        Main main = injector.getInstance(Main.class);

        main.tea.prepare();

    }

}
```

Now, let's say I have some random class, which needs my tea interface injected:

```
public class RandomClass {

    private Tea tea;

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.print("Doing stuff and.. ");
        tea.prepare();
    }

    public Tea getTea() {
        return tea;
    }

    @Inject
    public void setTea(Tea tea) {
        this.tea = tea;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this throws NullPointerException, because RandomClass is not aware of any injections from outside.

**Solutions I found so far**

1) I've read about creating custom Providers, such as:

```
public class TeaProvider implements Provider<Tea> {

    public Tea get() {
        Tea tea = new BlackTea();
        return tea;
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this solution requires creating new class in order to work:

```
//In main method
injector.injectMembers(new RandomClass());
```

2) Worse solution, is to inject injector inside RandomClass and manually asking for class instance, like so:

```
public class RandomClass {

    @Inject
    Injector injector;

    private Tea tea;

    public RandomClass() {
        tea = injector.getInstance(Tea.class);
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.print("Doing stuff and.. ");
        tea.prepare();
    }

}
```

Even so, I must get RandomClass instance from injector in my bootstrapping method.

**The questions**

I really don't get the whole concept of DI frameworks, if they require providing classes either way.

1) Is there any possible way to inject Tea instance into RandomClass without explicitly telling injecting in bootstrapping method to do so? If possible, then how?

2) What's the pros in using DI frameworks, if I've to manually "load" all classes to inject values? I mean, I can provide new instance of some class to the dependent without using frameworks at all. Then why people would use it?

Comment: how do you currently create your instance of `RandomClass`? So far I have never used setter injection but constructor injection. Wherever you need an instance of `RandomClass` you mark that instance as `@Inject` which will cause Guice to create an instance and injects *its* dependencies.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but using constructor injection forces me to create RandomClass instance from injector in main method. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: P.S. I can assure you that RandomClass is created somewhere, but not in the main class, it just doesn't fit there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind DI frameworks is simple: A class shouldn't be responsible for instantiating its dependencies. So, though I wouldn't recommend going this far, *a 100% DI solution should include zero calls to `new`*. It should happen entirely from a factory class.

Here's your `RandomClass` with no DI:

```
public class RandomClass {
    private Tea tea;

    public RandomClass() {
        tea = new BlackTea();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.print("Doing stuff and.. ");
        tea.prepare();
    }    
}
```

At this point, you should notice that it is *impossible* to test RandomClass without testing Tea's functionality, because you've provided no way to provide an alternative implementation.

Another way you could do it:

```
public class RandomClass {
    private Tea tea;

    public RandomClass(Tea tea) {
        this.tea = tea;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.print("Doing stuff and.. ");
        tea.prepare();
    }    
}

public class RandomClassProvider {
    public RandomClass create() {
        return new RandomClass(new BlackTea());
    }
}
```

Now, with DI annotations:

```
public class RandomClass {
    private Tea tea;

    @Inject public RandomClass(Tea tea) {
        this.tea = tea;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.print("Doing stuff and.. ");
        tea.prepare();
    }    
}

// Guice writes Provider<RandomClass> automatically.
```

Now you can use RandomClass manually (by calling the @Inject-annotated constructor) or automatically (just requesting an instance through Guice). This should make it easy to switch implementations, including to *switch implementations only in tests* to test doubles you've written or that you've created through Mockito.

**A final word about providers**: You shouldn't have to worry about Providers yourself: No matter how you bind an instance or provider, you can access it using `@Inject X` or `@Inject Provider<X>` anywhere in a constructor or field (or `getInstance` or `getProvider`). Inject a Provider if you're not sure you need an instance, or if you'll need more than one, and only write a Provider manually if you need to call some external method to get an instance if you need to postprocess.

Comment: I do understand most of it, but there're some keypoints, that aren't clear. Say, I have some sort of handler class, with concrete implementation for different tasks. Some tasks require interfaces provided, some not. I though I would inject dependencies where required at runtime, because the whole process is unpredictable and dynamic.1) Is it possible to do that? 2) Is there any difference between using constructor injection and field? Both ways require me to instantiate some root object using injector. Apparently, I can't instantiate objects with injected fields without injector?

Comment: 1) Yes; rather than calling `new TaskA()` or `new TaskB()` you would inject a `Provider<TaskA>` and `Provider<TaskB>` and call `get` on each to get a new instance. 2) There is no difference in what you can inject, but it's hard to make final fields work with field injection, and unless you have public setter methods or a public @Inject-annotated initialization method you may find it hard to create your object without an injector (for testing or non-DI usage).